# The role of a header file in compilation?

Tags: c++, compilation, header-files

We have been asked a question in a practice paper '**What is the role of the header file in compilation?** What are header guards used for in this context?'

A header file will have any declarations for classes which may be included in .cpp implementations. I understand that by including a header file in an implementation or other header file, it is possible for that code to know all the possible members of the class without knowing its implementation.

Having done a little reading through StackOverflow, some have suggested that header files can possibly slow down compilation ([Coding C++ (mostly) in header files vs .cpp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103111/coding-c-mostly-in-header-files-vs-cpp-files)) and that while a change to a header file will require a full rebuild of all implementations, while a change to an implementation does not require a full rebuild of the header file and all its implementations.

Would these be accurate? Is there any reason that a header file is necessary of beneficial in compilation and what role does it play?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do a search for "preprocessor".

Comment: a proper implementation and build system will not require full recompilation

Comment: So, what effect, if any, does the header file have on compilation?

Answer (score 0):

yes, although I would avoid using the term implementations for code files - people may think you are talking about the implementation of the class(es) in the headers, which could lead to confusion.

Also, changing a header file will not result in you needing to rebuild all the code files - only those which include (directly or otherwise) said header file.

Oh, and header guards are used to avoid the same file being included twice in a given compilation unit (resulting in redefinitions of things).